# How to find specific text with Python and return a print?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I want to use beautifulsoup to search for:
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)
You can find that text on: https://www.shodan.io/host/46.173.206.195
And I want to print: when it's found, print ''Apache found'' or else ''Apache not found''
How do I do this?
My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
import re
import urllib2
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
init()
s = requests.Session()
print(Fore.GREEN + 'Made by Zaseth.')
print(Fore.GREEN + "[*] If you get the following error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'")
print(Fore.GREEN + "[*] This error means that your target is not on Shodan.")
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
shodanURL = raw_input(Fore.GREEN + ("Your target IP: "))

r = s.get('https://www.shodan.io/host/' + shodanURL)
r.status_code = ('Shodan Status: ' + str(r.status_code))

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

openPorts = soup.find("meta", attrs={"name": "twitter:description"})["content"]
print(Fore.GREEN + (openPorts))

serviceDetails = iter(soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "service-details"}))
serviceMains = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "service-main"})

for serviceMain in serviceMains:
    currentService = next(serviceDetails)

    print(Fore.GREEN + ("Port: " + currentService.find("div", attrs={"class": "port"}).contents[0]))
    print(Fore.GREEN + ("Protocol: " + currentService.find("div", attrs={"class": "protocol"}).contents[0]))
    print(Fore.GREEN + ("State: " + currentService.find("div", attrs={"class": "state"}).contents[0]))
    print(Fore.GREEN + ("------"))

    serviceInfo = serviceMain.find("pre").contents[0]
    print(Fore.GREEN + (serviceInfo))
    print(Fore.GREEN + '[*] Header Done.')
    print(Fore.GREEN + '[*] SSL info response can sometimes be limited.')
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
```

I can't enter it here because it would be getting messed up.

Comment: Do **not** post links to code. Post the code *in the question itself as formatted text*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i already listed the reason. How do I make sure the code i add is correct? the lines are too long and it messes up.

Comment: Copy and paste directly from your text editor. Highlight, then press ctrl-k and it should format it automatically for you.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Alright done. Should be good now.

Comment: @JavaSwd What part of the code isn't working?

Comment: Read the title @TankorSmash

Comment: I want to make it to find a specific string on the page.

Comment: Break the problem down. Do you have  a webpage? Then it's just a matter of finding a string in a page right? We don't need to know how you got the string, only that you have a string and you need to find a subset in it.

Comment: @TankorSmash The problem: my code works, but how do I create a part that finds a string. Basically the string that I want to find is in this format: 
<div class="service-main">
<h3>Apache httpd<small>Version: 2.4.10</small></h3>
<pre>HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Date: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 16:50:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=86ed8ij1e2nn6f9jnksm1rh3s1; path=/
Location: http://89.203.143.2/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html

</pre>
How do I output that exact: Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)

Comment: That's much easier to solve. Can you edit out your question to remove the unrelated code (like the stuff that gets you the code from the server) and just show us the total string and the substring you want to find?

Comment: At that point, you'll probably find a duplicate question that can help you solve your problem though!

Comment: I tried to search for this but I didn't find my correct answer. I need to actually find the specific string and output it with a print.

Comment: What part of finding a substring in Python were you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware that there's an official Shodan API that allows IP-based lookups for free? And there's a [Python library for Shodan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shodan/1.6.9) that makes interacting with it very easy. Scraping the website is against the terms of service and will get you blocked long-term. Here is a simpler version of what you were trying to achieve:

```
from shodan import Shodan

api = Shodan("API KEY") # Visit https://account.shodan.io for your API key
host = api.host('46.173.206.195')

# The top-level "ports" property has a list of all the open ports
print('Open Ports: {}'.format(host['ports']))

# The "data" property contains a list of all the banners
for banner in host['data']:
    print('Port: {}'.format(banner['port']))
    print('Protocol: {}'.format(banner['transport']))
    print(banner['data'])
```